# Cronjob command starts 2 processes, for 1 python script

Tags: bash, cron, kill-process

My crontab had the command:

> 50 08 * * 1-5 /home/MY_SCRIPT.py /home/arguments 2> /dev/null
>
> 59 23 * * 1-5 killall MY_SCRIPT.py

Which worked perfectly fine, but when I used to do

> ps aux | grep SCRIPT

It showed:

> myuser 13898 0.0 0.0 4444 648 ? Ss 08:50 0:00 /bin/sh -c /home/MY_SCRIPT.py /home/arguments 2> /dev/null
>
> myuser 13900 0.0 0.0 25268 7384 ? S 08:50 0:00 /usr/bin/python /home/MY_SCRIPT.py /home/arguments

- Why are 2 processes been shown?
  And the killall command also used to work fine.

I made a change to my script and in order to get the new behaviour, I had to kill the currently running scripts and I used

> kill 13898 13900

After that I used the same command (as in crontab)

> /home/MY_SCRIPT.py /home/arguments 2> /dev/null

- But now after restarting the script, it showed only 1 process (which makes sense)

Everything looks good till here, but this time the killall MY_SCRIPT in the cronjob didnt work, it said could not find pid. And the script kept on running until I had to manually kill it.

Need to find out the reason for this behaviour:

1. Why 2 processes from cronjob
2. Is there something wrong the way I restrated the script
3. How do I make sure that next time I restart the script, the cron should kill it for sure

OS:Linux Ubuntu

Comment: OS name ? Unix or Linux ? I got simmilar problem on HP UX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing two processes because crontab uses `/bin/sh` to summon your python script. So basically what happens is:

```
/bin/sh -c '/home/MY_SCRIPT.py /home/arguments 2> /dev/null'
```

And the process structure becomes

```
/bin/sh -> /usr/bin/python
```

Try this format instead:

```
50 08 * * 1-5 /bin/sh -c 'exec /home/MY_SCRIPT.py /home/arguments 2> /dev/null'
```

It may also be a good idea to specify the full path to `killall`. It's probably in `/usr/bin`. Verify it with `which killall`.

```
59 23 * * 1-5 /usr/bin/killall MY_SCRIPT.py
```

Another more efficient way to do it is to save your process id somewhere:

```
50 08 * * 1-5 /bin/sh -c 'echo "$$" > /var/run/my_script.pid; exec /home/MY_SCRIPT.py /home/arguments 2> /dev/null'
```

And use a more efficient **killer**:

```
59 23 * * 1-5 /bin/sh -c 'read PID < /var/run/my_script.pid; kill "$PID"'
```